# Why does my jQuery filter only work once on this select element?

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I'm trying to filter results based on what a user selects in a select form. Here is my HTML:

```
<li>
Colour Options
<select name="item_options[cf_product_option_colour]" id="product-multiple-1">
    <option>Choose Option</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="Green">Green</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
</select>
</li>
<li>
Size Options
<select name="item_options[cf_product_option_size]" id="product-multiple-2">
    <option>Choose Option</option>
    <option value="75643" class="Red">5ml - £1.00</option>
    <option value="765432" class="Red">10ml - £2.00</option>
    <option value="867564534" class="Red">15ml - £3.00</option>
    <option value="5434" class="Red">20ml - £4.00</option>
    <option value="6453234" class="Green">5ml - £1.00</option>
    <option value="45256536" class="Green">10ml - £2.00</option>
    <option value="52454" class="Green">15ml - £3.00</option>
    <option value="6543754" class="Blue">5ml - £1.00</option>
    <option value="4316243" class="Blue">10ml - £2.00</option>
</select>
</li>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("#product-multiple-1").change(function(){
    var matches = $("#product-multiple-2 > option." + $(this).val());
    $("#product-multiple-2").empty().html(matches);
    console.log(matches);
    return matches;
});
```

What should happen, is when I choose a colour option, it changes the size options drop down. This seems to work when I choose the first colour option, but then if I choose another colour option, it doesn't do anything.

I inspected it and looked at the console. It seems to run the variable once, but then when I try select another option, the variable is blank and in console it just displays `[]`

Any help would be good :)

Comment: jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uazKL/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, when you replace the options the first time , the only options in the second select have the class of the first color and all the other color classes are gone. If I click on RED first, get red class in second. Now click on GREEN and it returns no match so the select gets emptied.

A simple fix would be cache a clone of the options.

```
var $options= $('#product-multiple-2 option');
$("#product-multiple-1").change(function(){
    var matches = $options.filter('.'+$(this).val()).clone();
    $("#product-multiple-2").html(matches);
});
```

Now you can go back to the well as often as needed  . Trying to hide options does not work in IE

Comment: This seems to work the best. I've never come across the clone method. Will look into that.

Answer (score 2):

When you do the first `empty()`, you don't have any other options any more, only the red ones.
So, for example, when you run it for the first time, selecting Red on select1, you get only the red options in select 2 - FOREVER!
When you run the second time, Green for example, there are no Green options in select2, so you get an empty nodelist.
you should use jQuery's hide() and show(), like this:

```
$("#product-multiple-1").change(function(){
        var matches = $("#product-multiple-2 option." + $(this).val());
        $("#product-multiple-2 option").not('.'+ $(this).val()).css('display', 'none');
        matches.css('display', 'block'))
        return matches;
    });
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but when i run that, it doesn't work? I can't get my head around making option elements hiding and showing using this.

Comment: that's what hide() and show() do, change css display...try it in IE..fail

Answer (score 2):

you are removing all elements that have a different class than the selected options value:

```
$("#product-multiple-2").empty().html(matches);
```

the line is effectively removing all options first, then adds the ones that matched on the line before.

you could instead hide everything: (approximately)

```
$("#product-multiple-2 option").hide();
matches.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are removing the items that don't match so when you select a different colour, the items for that colour are gone.

Save the originals and reload them instead like this:

```
var productMultiple2 = $("#product-multiple-2");
productMultiple2.data('originalOptions', productMultiple2.html());
$("#product-multiple-1").change(function(){   
    var val = $(this).val();
    productMultiple2.html(productMultiple2.data('originalOptions'));
    if (val !== "Choose Option") {  
        $("#product-multiple-2 > option").filter(function() {
            return !$(this).is("." + val) && $(this).val() !== "Choose Option";
        }).remove();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uazKL/5/

Fixed to not break with "Choose Option"

Comment: hide() with option tag is futile in IE

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because you're removing all the options from the second select tag in order to display the ones with a class that matches the first select's value.

There's two (maybe more?) things you can do:

1. You can keep a copy of the option elements in a variable and then grab the elements you want like so:

   ```
   var $options = $("#product-multiple-2 > option");
   $("#product-multiple-1").change(function(){
       var $matches = $options.filter("." + $(this).val());
       $("#product-multiple-2").empty().html($matches);
       console.log($matches);
   });
   ```
2. You can disable the options that are not available in the second select like so:

   ```
   $("#product-multiple-1").change(function(){
       $("#product-multiple-2 > option").each(function(index, elem) {
           if ($(elem).is("." + $(this).val())) {
               elem.disabled = false;
           } else {
               elem.disabled = true;
           }
       });
       console.log($matches);
   });
   ```